# SqlDatasource SQL query help needed?

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, webforms

HI

I am using a webform and a SQLDataSource, I am using query builder its for a grid view. I want to get a certain amount of characters frm a column in the table just say 1 line from a paragraph. How do I do it in query builder? is it possibe if no, how would i do it?

Thanks in Advanced!

NewbieProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

To get first 100 characters modify your SQL to look like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING ( myColumn , 1 , 100 ) 
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Cheers pal, gonna try it now :)

Comment: A field or property with the name 'ProdDescription' was not found on the selected data source.

Comment: Hmmm, if ProdDescription is a column in the table you are querying you should not get that error.  Can you post your query?

Comment: yeh i got:

SELECT        SUBSTRING(ProgDescription, 0, 100), ProductID, ProductName, ProdPrice
FROM            Prods

Comment: Sorry I was doing someting wrong, its wokring now thanks pal ur a star!! 

Have you any idea how i can do that substring for 100 characters and at the end of 100 characters have someting like three dots? ...